hexrays and ida tags ... are they ever supposed to be used together?
Most of the questions tagged hexrays tend to be solely about functionality of the plugin rather than the base IDA software on which the plugin depends.
Should questions about the HexRays plugin also always mention ida or should we leave that for special cases where the inquirer actually also refers to something in the disassembly view, say?
Just from the perspective of having a maximum number of tags per question, I'd think cutting out ida from hexrays questions more sensible, but that's why I am asking you!

For the sake of completeness I'll simply put forward my proposal which could probably also be deduced from the question:
Let's remove ida from questions which have both ida and hexrays and don't reference a feature also found in IDA (without the decompiler plugin).
